# Angular material expandable table doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I want to reproduce the "Table with expandable rows" example from https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples. I've created a new Angular project, added Angular material and literally copied the example content into my project. And yet, the rows are not expanding as in the example. I'm trying different imports, different styles - nothing. What am I missing?

Here's how it looks:
[image]

Here's my project on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fc2cyw-ftpmac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Edited Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fc2cyw-wtqvd4

Change the style url from table.component.html to table.component.css

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  styleUrls: ['table.component.html'],
  templateUrl: 'table.component.css',
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0'})),
      state('expanded', style({height: '*'})),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
```

Comment: Whoa, I've spend so much time on that, and I didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the CSS file of the expandable table:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr.example-detail-row {
  height: 0;
}

tr.example-element-row:not(.example-expanded-row):hover {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

tr.example-element-row:not(.example-expanded-row):active {
  background: #efefef;
}

.example-element-row td {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}

.example-element-detail {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.example-element-diagram {
  min-width: 80px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 8px 0;
  height: 104px;
}

.example-element-symbol {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: normal;
}

.example-element-description {
  padding: 16px;
}

.example-element-description-attribution {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).